# How to install avidemux?

Tags: 11.10

I recently upgraded to Oneiric Beta 1, and now I need to use avidemux to convert some video files. It seems that it's been removed and when I try to install it, I receive the following:

```
Package avidemux is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
   libavidemux0
E: Package 'avidemux' has no installation candidate
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be solved when last I upgraded to `3.0.0-13-generic #22-Ubuntu`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oneiric is in beta - as such some packages have not been successfully built or some other change has caused a build problem.

Please track this on Launchpad - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/avidemux/+bug/831096

Answer (score 4):

There is no avidemux in Oneiric (yet(?)). Neither a `libavidemux0` according to the ubuntu packages page it seems.

But you can find the `.deb` files for `amd64` or `i386` on [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/avidemux). Download all the files you need for your version and then use Ubuntu Software Center to install these.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that. And, maybe it's better to wait a bit for the bugs to get fixed for the release.

Answer (score 0):

You can't install the .deb from Launchpad, there is a missing dependency (libx264-98).
In Ocelot's repositories is libx264-116 instaled, but don't takes it.

The package that not installs is "avidemux-plugins-common" so, avidemux installs ok and opens good, but how there's no plugins you don't have audio and the video builded with errors.

Sorry about my english... I try it